# Which linearisation technique is correct?

Tags: linearization, nonlinear-programming

I have the objective function (Maximally Diverse Grouping Problem) as

$$\max\sum_{g=1}^G\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}d_{ij}x_{ig}x_{jg}$$

Here, $d_{ij}$ are known parameters, and $x_{ig}$ and $x_{jg}$ are binary variables.

It is nonlinear as we have the bilinear term, $x_{ig}x_{jg}$.

#### Linearization Technique 1

We can linearise it by introducing an binary variable $z_{ijg}=x_{ig}x_{jg}$

\begin{align}z_{ijg} &\le x_{ig}\\z_{ijg} &\le x_{jg}\\z_{ijg}&\ge x_{ig}+x_{jg}-1\end{align}

Now, the new objection function becomes

$$\max\sum_{g=1}^G\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}d_{ij}z_{ijg}$$

#### Linearization Technique 2

I do not introduce any extra variables. Instead I rewrite the objective function as

$$\max\sum_{g=1}^G\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}d_{ij}(x_{ig}+x_{jg}-1)$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are equivalent except when $x_{i,g}=x_{j,g}=0$, in which case the second linearization incorrectly contributes $-d_{ij}$ to the objective.

Assuming $d_{ij} \ge 0$, I recommend a third linearization (relaxing $z$ and omitting two constraints from linearization 1):
\begin{align}
z_{ijg}&\ge x_{ig}+x_{jg}-1 \\
z_{ijg}&\ge 0
\end{align}

Comment: Dear Rob, may check with you if my reasoning is correct since the x variables have already been defined to be binary, through the first inequality of your reply, it is inconsequential even if z has been relaxed as x will force it to be either 1 or 0. Through relaxing it does it help to boost solution speed? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, if $d>0$ and $x$ is declared binary, $z$ will automatically be binary-valued even if you relax to $z \ge 0$. Relaxing $z$ might or might not speed things up, but that is the motivation. A best practice is to try it both ways on realistic instances.

Comment: Thank you, Rob!

Comment: I see now that you have changed the objective sense from minimization to maximization, and that invalidates my answer. For maximization, you should instead keep the other two ($\le$) constraints.